# Dynamically adding a DropDownList / SelectList to a div using Razor layout

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am building a form in a Razor layout that has a DropDownList and a text box

Below this, there's would be an "add another" link.

Clicking this, I need to add another DropDownList and TextBox pair to the div (let's call this #socialNetworks)

Currently, I do this using jQuery like this for 'normal' / one off text boxes:

```
    var phoneFieldsIndex = 0;

    $('#addAnotherPhoneLink').click(function () {

        if ($('#phoneFields input:last').val()) {

            phoneFieldsIndex++;

            $('#phoneFields').append('<input name="phone[' + emailFieldsIndex + ']" type="text"><br />');

        }

    });
```

This works fine - when clicking the a element with addAnotherPhoneLink, another input box (with the index incremented) is added to the div #phoneFields

I'm trying to do something similar with my DropDownList / Input pair

However, for the DropDownList, I currently have:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SocialNetwork", new SelectList(Model.AvailableSocialNetworks))

<input name="Username" type="text" />
```

So, I see there's two problems here:

- **I need to increment the index of the SocialNetwork DropDownList each time**
- **I need the values in Model.AvailableSocialNetworks to be replicated for each**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery to copy one of the existing `select` lists (or use the server to provide a hidden one as a template and copy that).

```
var newSelect = $('#phoneFields select:first-child').clone()
   .attr("name", 'SocialNetwork[' + emailFieldsIndex + ']');

$('#phoneFields').append(newSelect);
```

I assume the index will be the same as for the `input` box you are adding at the same time?